# how we cam make a sharp edge of div from middle in css?

Tags: html, css

I want to make a div with something like this.

[image]

After twitter circle the edge is showing in middle. How can i make it? Please any one can help me. I try a lot but i am not succeed. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Something like this ?

```css
body {background:#FFFFFF;padding:20px}

p {background:black; -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
-moz-border-radius: 10px;
border-radius: 10px; width:250px; height:50px}

.arrow_div{border:solid 10px transparent;border-right-color:#000;position:absolute;margin:-50px 0 0 -20px;}
```

```html
<p></p>
<div class="arrow_div"></div>
```

change your div **color**, **height** , **width** , according to your need.